# Ajax POST request issue with Flask Restless

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, ajax

I'm trying to use `jQuery` and `Ajax` to send a `POST` request to my API.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Orders',
    headers: {
        contentType: "application/json"
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({'description':'test'}),
});
```

When I'm using `postman` (chrome extension) the `POST` request is fine and everything works great.

If I'm trying to use the above code with `AJAX` the response is:

```
message:"Request must have "Content-Type: application/json" header"
```

I find it really weird because I set `contentType : "application/json"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have tried to set the property dataType to JSON?

Your code will looks like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/api/Orders',
   headers: {
      contentType: "application/json"
   },
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify({'description':'test'}),

   dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Again the same error. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After 6 hours i found the correct answer.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Orders',
        headers: {
            accepts: 'application/vnd.api+json'
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        type : 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'description' : 'test'
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```